# Many authors' profiles are missing in https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, blog

I was going through https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/ and could not find the profiles of many authors (including the CEO of Stack Overflow).

[image: Screenshot of https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/]

Please add the profiles of all the authors.

Comment: I was asking myself if Philippe has penned any articles on *The Overflow* and indeed [here is one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/07/29/the-loop-our-community-public-platform-roadmap-for-q3-2021/). There are also other authors missing from the list.

Comment: Who is that Philippe guy anyway… ;) on a more serious note, [Ryan Donovan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/584503/ryan-donovan), who manages the editorial doesn’t have a description there either.

Comment: It looks like most of the authors of recent posts on the blog – even those who've written dozens of posts – aren't listed on that authors page, actually (even though every page on the blog seems to include a "posts by author" link to that page at the bottom)... It may be worth editing this post to indicate the broader issue.

Comment: @V2Blast I have edited the post :)

Comment: That Philippe guy is trouble, that’s who he is. :-). (Ps - will follow up on this question).

Answer (score 3):

The marketing team is currently in the process of adding profiles for authors where they were blank. Prashanth's profile has been added already.

Comment: *Prashanth's profile has been added already.* ... the marketing team secured their Christmas Bonus ;)

Comment: BTW, what is the correct spelling? Chabanovskii or Chabanovsky? In MSE profile the spelling is different and in blog the spelling is different.

Comment: Half year later, many are still blank. It's OK to reject such request if updating avatars is too much work for the marketing team (it might be technically complicated), but please let us know that's the case.